# Docker DNS ignoring /etc/nsswitch.conf on host

Tags: docker, nginx, networking

I have an `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file that adds `libvirt-nss`, so that vm hostnames are automatically resolved on the host machine and in guest machines. I then have an nginx container (with `--network host`) running on the host, that routes traffic to some services on the host, and the rest to the virtual machines. The nginx container however cannot resolve the hostnames of the virtual machines, and I suspect the docker engine (?) does not respect `/etc/nsswitch.conf` of the host to resolve domain names. Is there any way to get this working or am I out of luck?

Comment: The container has its own `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file; an Alpine-based image might not be able to honor that at all (since it has a fairly minimal libc implementation).  For this particular setup you might find it more straightforward to run Nginx directly on the host.

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidMaze pointed out, this is by design. There are several ways to achieve what you seem to be trying to do.

You can add an `nsswitch.conf` file to the container. This does work in Alpine. Either copy it in the `Dockerfile` or use a bind mount:

```
$ docker run --rm -v /etc/nsswitch.conf:/etc/nsswitch.conf --add-host foobar.dns:8.8.8.8 busybox ping foobar.dns
PING foobar.dns (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=113 time=7.796 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=113 time=7.809 ms
```

You can then use `docker --add-host` to add hostnames to the container's `hostfile`. Alternatively, bind your host's `hosts` file as well:

```
$ docker run --rm -v /etc/nsswitch.conf:/etc/nsswitch.conf -v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts busybox ping foobar.dns
PING foobar.dns (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=113 time=16.961 ms
```

Comment: Forgot to mention in my question, but I do run the container with `--network host` but that doesn't do it

Comment: @rosengrenen You're right that `--network host` alone doesn't work, but see my expanded example in the answer which will work.

Comment: I tried something like that but it didn't quite work since I have `libvirt` and `libvirt_guest` entries in the hosts section of the `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and `libvirt-nss` and `virsh` and all those things are not available inside the container, so it just throws a system error when trying to resolve domains. As mentioned in a comment to my question by @David Maze I might have to resort to running nginx on the host without docker in this particular case